# How to customize SearchHeadline in django full text search?

Tags: python, django, full-text-search, django-3.1

I want to highlight search terms with SearchHeadline. My code is somethink like this:

```
query = SearchQuery('cat')
vector = SearchVector('caption')
Post.objects.annotate(
    search=vector
    headline=SearchHeadline(
        'caption',
        query
    )
).filter(search=query)
```

This code works well and for example the headline of the first result is:

```
'My <b>cat</b> breed is Persian. Persian cats are the most beautiful breed.'
```

As you can see `cat` is highlighted but `cats` is not, and I want to highlight all of `cat` string in the caption, like this:

```
'My <b>cat</b> breed is Persian. Persian <b>cat</b>s are the most beautiful breed.'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use icontains to search the particular term in words and sentences.

```
query = SearchQuery('cat')
vector = SearchVector('caption')
Post.objects.annotate(
    search=vector
    headline=SearchHeadline(
        'caption',
        query
    )
).filter(search__icontains=query)
```